# Logging on WebAssembly seems to ignore LogLevels lower than Information

Tags: c#, logging, blazor, blazor-webassembly, serilog

I'm testing **ILoggers** in a **Blazor WASM** application because I'd like to see Debug logs when I enable them. I tried changing the appsettings file to set the Default loglevel but it seems the only the logs from Information and upwards are showed on console.

My current **appsettings.json** file look like this:

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.BrowserConsole" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "BrowserConsole" }
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is how I'm setting the logger:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Inside of the Index.razor page I have a foreach that it's being used to log various messages using a different level.

```cs
foreach (var level in Enum.GetValues(typeof(LogLevel)).Cast<LogLevel>())
{
    Logger.Log(level, level.ToString());
}
```

Using **Serilog** is not a must, I'll even settle for just the default logger but I want to have the certainty that modifying the file and lowering the **LogLevel** I'll see even the other logs.

What am I getting wrong?

I already tried:

- manually settings minimum loglevel on the **Program.cs**;
- separating appsettings file and putting the configuration on a **appsettings.Development.json** file;
- using **Serilog** instead of default logger.

Comment: It sounds to me like the logger configuration used above is running server-side; is this definitely in the client-side app initialization?

Answer (score 0):

It is like it is, because this is what the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/logging?view=aspnetcore-8.0) says:

`On the server, logging only occurs to the server-side .NET console in the Development environment at the LogLevel.Information level or higher.`

So, you wont be able to see Debug level logs in WebAssembly.
And if you want to ask why they did that, the answer is:

This is done to prevent spamming the console with too much debug information, and for sure also for security reasons.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I'm trying to set the minimum level to warning but I still see the Information log.

Comment: @ImZac thats another issue, please do not mix every encountered problem alltogether in one question. I wrote you an answer for the problem mentioned in a question, and pointed out what documentation says about the problem that you are facing. If you have a another problem, firstly search thorough stackoverflow for solution, and if it's not mentioned in any other question, ask another one.